# Can't get the html of a page using requests.get() python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Here is my code:

```
response = requests.get('URL HERE', headers=header, params=param, cookies=cookie)
print(response.content)
```

I also tried this:

```
print(response.text)
```

But both return this:

```
'<script>window.location="URL HERE";</script>'
```

All I want is to get the html of the page.
Any ideas?

EDIT:

I don't know how I did it, but I got the header and the cookie again from the website and plugged them in and it worked. I think it might be because I use Firefix and I had an update so maybe the header changed IDK.

Comment: Is it possible that I can get the url?

Comment: ok. Here "https://de-legalization.tlscontact.com/eg/CAI/myapp.php". This the url I want the html of. You need to sign in in order to reach this page, but that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is the HTML of the whole page. Unfortunately, the page seems to require JavaScript, which your approach does not support. I don't know much about JS, but it seems to be a function that redirects you to a different page.
You could use an approach based on Selenium if the website only works when JS is enabled.

Comment: Well I do use selenium in a different part of the project but this part is continuously checking for changes in the page so i feel like selenium isn't that efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The website you used seems to redirect people when I went to the link, so when you get the url, make sure to allow redirects.

Do this:

`response = requests.get('URL HERE', headers=header, params=param, cookies=cookie, allow_redirects=True)`

Comment: It redirects you to the login page but i give the program the header and cookie and when i type ```print(response.url)``` i get the url that i want. But I tried it anyways and still, same result.